# WebBrowser Control and Wininet APIs

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, fiddler, wininet

Is it possible to get the exact all Http Request Header and Http Response Header details from WebBrowser control?

Also is there any means of getting WinInet related HINTERNET handle from WebBrowser Control?

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do that with the WebBrowser Control.

You might consider integrating [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore) into your application; that would allow you to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have used FiddlerCore but it updates proxy settings for all application using internet/Intranet like IE,outlook etc... i want fiddler core to monitor request going from webbrowser control in my application. can i able to achieve using FiddlerCore?

Comment: If you're saying: "I want FiddlerCore to capture traffic only from my application and not everything, yes, you can do that. Don't register as the system proxy, and look at the method in the URLMon class instead.

Comment: I tried using URLMonInterop.SetProxyInProcess("127.0.0.1:8888", ""); Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, false,false); but not able to monitor traffic from web browser control in application. can you please share some sample?

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor for WebBrowser http requests that are send/get and data send/get with this  library:

Http Monitor for Webbrowser Control

it is here
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/HttpMonitor.aspx

it is beta, but works for me.. 
there  are demo sample and source codes.
you must register their dll by regsvr32  for demo working